# Android: Is there a way to create hidden folders and hidden files?

Tags: android, hidden-files

I am a newbie android developer. I need to know if there is a way to create hidden folders and hidden files in android programatically. There must be a way to create hidden folders in sdcard. But I don't know how? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't use Android <del>(Read: *this answer may be entirely wrong*)</del>. However...

Since Android has *IX roots, then any file (or directory) beginning with a period ('.') *should* be hidden. Be warned, however, that this is merely a convention (to prevent the files from being listed in certain default conditions) and does not add any privacy or security to the files.

Happy coding.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, then please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the small tick mark at the left side of the posted answer.

Comment: 1k views for this answer? I was expecting a small, quick'n'dirty rootkit. :(